# Panoply error - "There was an exception preparing the data. Scaling coefficient must be in range [-1000, 1000]"

Tags: panoply

I am trying to create a plot in panoply, but it just keep showing error "There was an exception preparing the data. Scaling coefficient must be in range [-1000, 1000]" How can I solve it?

[image: error]